# Poisson process: Has my book used a necessary condition, when it should have used a sufficient condition?

Tags: probability, logic, stochastic-processes

My book says that **if we know that if we are viewing a poisson process with length $t$, and know that $n$ events happened in that interval, than the time that any of those events happened is uniformly distributed with probability $1/t$**, I do not doubt that this is true, but I am wondering if the logic my book uses is correct.

They say that what I wrote above must hold because of this theorem:

[image: pic]

Now, I am wondering why the logic holds. What I mean is:

Lets say we know that all the events are uniformly distributed, then we know that the $S$s must have the distribution of the order statistics. And hence we have the result above, so the result theorem above become a necessary condition.

But conversely, let's say we know that the $S$s have the distribution of the order statistics of $n$ independent random variables uniformly distributed on $[0,t]$. Can we then say that the random variables the order statistics represent is uniform on $[0,t]$, and hence the above theorem is a sufficient condition for what I wrote first?

**Maybe(?) another way of asking the question is:** I guess it is pretty clear that the order statistics are described clearly by the random variables?, but conversely if we have the order statistics, is it clear what kind of random variables we are dealing with?

Comment: If you know the joint distribution of $n$ continuous random variables, then you know everything there is to know about them.  What else do you mean by "what kind of random variables [are we] dealing with"?

Comment: Hello @mjqxxxx, What I mean is, if you have the joint distribution n random variables, then you can(in theory) calculate the joint distribution of the order statistics. But lets say you have n random variables, but you do not know their joint or marginal distribution, you only know their joint order statistics distribution, can you then calculate the joint distribution of the original random variables?

Comment: Or said another way, I am pretty sure for every joint distribution, there is a corresponding unique joint order statistics distribution, but for every joint order statistics distribution, is there a unique joint distribution for the random variables these order statistcs represent?

Comment: No, because in general knowing the distribution of the order statistics doesn't tell you anything about the distribution of the *ranks* of the random variables.

Comment: You might want to add MathJax to replace the image that has now gone offline and rendered your question unanswerable.